# Hosting a web gl game on Facebook Canvas

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

So.. I've been trying to host my web gl build on somewhere that facebook can work with but got no luck so far...

I have tried google drive, and although I can play from the google drive address I cant get it to work on Facebook Canvas (reason in here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1095845/facebook-canvas-and-webgl-problem.html)

I have also given heroku a try but it didn't seem to work... I think I just need more help on that (I have uploaded the files but instead of 300mb of total only half of them were uploaded... if someone knows how to host web gl on heroku pls help)

So any ideas??

Are there any free solutions? And if not, are there any ssl hosting plans cheap enough for this?

Answer (score 0):

WebGL is just JavaScript with HTML5 Canvas, you can put that on pretty much every host. Since you need SSL for Canvas, here are some cheap (and free) options:

- https://letsencrypt.org/
- https://www.startssl.com/

About heroku, there are many tutorials about how to deploy, maybe you ran out of space?: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app

You can try deploying a simple html/js file and see how it works on Facebook Canvas.

Comment: Ok so after a lot of searching and testing a few sites I ended up with amazon's aws. So i managed to host my game with https at   https://shadowhunters.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html  

It runs perfect just like google drive.

However, when I put it on facebook I get the following error:
PreconditionFailedAt least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not holdBucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data09E91DA867B8093BBnyza7TdztBAJhoNk9m2I9ZjL9D3dtPetoqJ8/3zGR93Izr28oq+CX34avwRFfRdrl2w0uqayQ8=

Comment: i used google for you and came up with plenty of articles, for example: http://blog.svnlabs.com/amazon-s3-facebook-fanpage-app/ - in general, just put an error message into google. you are most likely never the first one who got the error ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you build the Unity game for WebGL there will be a index.html file. Now follow the steps below

1. Step 1. Change the index.html to index.php
2. Step 2. Create an account to https://www.heroku.com/
3. Step 3. Create a new app inside heroku.com, in the setting window you will find a git link.
4. Step 4: Clone that git repo to your Local computer and Push the whole WebGl build (Remember to change index.html to index.php).
5. Step 5: Congrats, you are done. Now visit the site, you can get the site link from your heroku dash board.

N.B : if you don't know how to push git you can see this tutorial. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9l4hmvcpWk